# HTML form POST using JS or AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I already know two ways of posting an html form using ajax.

for example..

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
      $("#clientInfo").submit(function(event) {
          message = $('#name').val();
      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();
      var $form = $(this),
          url = 'post2.php';

      /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
      var posting = $.post(url, { message: message });



    });
</script>
```

that works fine, but it only works if I call event.preventDefault() which will stop the page from an actual submitting,

return false could also be used.

my problem is, is it possible to post without stopping the actual submission? without the need of event.preventDefault() and return false? I want the page to submit normally but I need to post some data while that is happening.

please advice.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. If the `action` and `method` are set in the form and `name`'s are on inputs there is no need for the ajax. The form will send data in same format as `$.post`

Comment: post is a method to communicate with the server. Inorder to submit you need any of the http methods

Answer (score 1):

event.preventDefault() is used to prevent the form element's default action of navigating to another URL or page on submission. If you want that you can navigate to another page manually. Otherwise preventDefault is used to keep the action page based so that ajax (asynchronous js) can be used effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you can do it by

1. prevent default
2. send your data
3. submitting again by js.

Something like this:

```
    //the namespace of event would help the unbinding after
$("#clientInfo").bind('submit.waitSubmittion', function(event) {
    message = $('#name').val();

    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        url = 'post2.php';

    /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
    var posting = $.post(url, { message: message }, function(){
        //after we sure the call made,
        //unbind our event (including prevent default) and submit the form
        $form.unbind('submit.waitSubmittion').trigger('submit')
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$("#clientInfo").on('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = $(this).serializeArray();
 $.ajax({
   url : 'whatever.php', // page where you are sending data
   type : 'post',
   data : data,
   success : function(data){
     alert(data); // do whatever you want
   }
 });
});
```